# what is khostd?

Tags: linux, centos, ps

I see this process but can't seem to find anything about it on Google:

```
init─┬─crond
     ├─dbus-daemon
     ├─events/0
     ├─events/1
     ├─httpd───8*[httpd]
     ├─khelper
     ├─khostd───khostd
     ├─klogd
     ├─ksoftirqd/0
```

What is khostd? Is it useful?

I'm using a Centos 5.4 64bit system.

**More Info after getting pidof khostd:**

```
/proc/28069:
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root 0 Oct 19 18:44 attr
-r-------- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 auxv
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:44 cmdline
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 coredump_filter
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 cpuset
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 cwd -> /tmp
-r-------- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 environ
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:44 exe -> /usr/lib/.khostd/khostd
dr-x------ 2 root root 0 Oct 19 18:44 fd
dr-x------ 2 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 fdinfo
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 io
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 limits
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 loginuid
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 maps
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 mem
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 mounts
-r-------- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 mountstats
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 numa_maps
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 oom_adj
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 oom_score
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 root -> /
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 schedstat
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 smaps
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:44 stat
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:44 statm
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:44 status
dr-xr-xr-x 3 root root 0 Oct 19 18:44 task
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Oct 19 18:46 wchan

ls -l fd
total 0
lr-x------ 1 root root 64 Oct 19 18:44 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Oct 19 18:44 1 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Oct 19 18:44 2 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Oct 19 18:44 3 -> socket:[243807]

lsof -a -p 28069
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE     SIZE    NODE NAME
khostd  28069 root  cwd    DIR    3,1     4096 6717441 /tmp
khostd  28069 root  rtd    DIR    3,1     4096       2 /
khostd  28069 root  txt    REG    3,1  2976132 6717448 /usr/lib/.khostd/khostd
khostd  28069 root  mem    REG    3,1   125736 9110591 /lib/ld-2.5.so
khostd  28069 root  mem    REG    3,1  1611564 9109521 /lib/libc-2.5.so
khostd  28069 root  mem    REG    3,1   208352 9109572 /lib/libm-2.5.so
khostd  28069 root  mem    REG    3,1   129716 9109534 /lib/libpthread-2.5.so
khostd  28069 root  mem    REG    3,1    16428 9109528 /lib/libdl-2.5.so
khostd  28069 root  mem    REG    3,1   101404 9110587 /lib/libnsl-2.5.so
khostd  28069 root  mem    REG    3,1   127661 6717504 /tmp/pdk-root/e6435b00fc79422519aa88bd9ce23223/POSIX.so
khostd  28069 root  mem    REG    3,1    18503 6717495 /tmp/pdk-root/34a1a6c9d35316e363f0994128ef61e6/Fcntl.so
khostd  28069 root  mem    REG    3,1 56454896 1118201 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
khostd  28069 root  mem    REG    3,1  1264090 6717493 /tmp/pdk-root/fcb734befe617ec3ae1edc38da810a5a/libperl.so
khostd  28069 root  mem    REG    3,1    46680 9109544 /lib/libnss_files-2.5.so
khostd  28069 root  mem    REG    3,1    13420 9109560 /lib/libutil-2.5.so
khostd  28069 root  mem    REG    3,1    45288 9109538 /lib/libcrypt-2.5.so
khostd  28069 root  mem    REG    3,1    26835 6717512 /tmp/pdk-root/3760d3688c78b22765b55d36a88382f4/FastCalc.so
khostd  28069 root  mem    REG    3,1    20493 6717510 /tmp/pdk-root/9319229253f468feb2a6076b8f5b0492/IO.so
khostd  28069 root  mem    REG    3,1    28572 6717506 /tmp/pdk-root/ff58a81c4ba367275c0ac887821ec093/Socket.so
khostd  28069 root    0r   CHR    1,3             1201 /dev/null
khostd  28069 root    1w   CHR    1,3             1201 /dev/null
khostd  28069 root    2w   CHR    1,3             1201 /dev/null
khostd  28069 root    3u  IPv4 243807              TCP *:etlservicemgr (LISTEN)
```

**More info after looking into the .khostd directory:**

```
ls -la
total 4188
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       4096 Oct 13 16:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 59 root root      36864 Oct 18 16:47 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      13096 Sep  4  2009 chat
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     157760 Sep  4  2009 find
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     711660 Mar 29  2011 hi
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        334 Aug 16 17:07 .hostconf
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      60920 Sep  4  2009 iptables
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    2976132 Aug 23 13:59 khostd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      14864 Sep  4  2009 kill
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     125920 May 25  2008 nstat
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root root      83696 Jan 21  2009 ps
-rwx--s--x  1 root slocate   28184 Sep  4  2009 slocate

cat .hostconf
bindport=9001
trustip=[Lots of comma separated IP addresses here]
heartserver=open.hichina.com
heartserver_port=3001
reportserver=open.hichina.com
reportserver_port=3001
version=Unix2.01
```

Comment: Also noticed, after a while, iptables -L would show a new rule allowing access to port 9001. Looks like the hosting provider is trying to override some of the programs on the server.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

> Also noticed, after a while, `iptables -L` would show a new rule
>   allowing access to port 9001. Looks like the hosting provider is trying to override some of the programs on the server.
>
> I did a killall on it and it restarted itself. I'm suspecting this is a program that was inserted by my cloud hosting provider.

Contact them to ask. But I'm afraid that your system is infected with a rootkit:

```
reportserver=open.hichina.com
reportserver_port=3001
```

Take a look at the network connections:

```
# netstat -natp | grep :9001 | less
```

or you probably want to sniff some packets on this port:

```
# tcpdump -vv -s0 -c 500 tcp port 9001 -w /tmp/khostd.pcap
```

copy to your laptop and open with Wireshark to see what does it say.

[rkhunter](http://www.rootkit.nl/) and [chkrootkit](http://www.chkrootkit.org/) may also help, if you find something doubtful, the best way is... fresh reinstall.

---

Determine its PID with:

```
pidof khostd
pgrep khostd
```

and take a look at this `/proc/$(pidof khostd)/`.

Some info can help:

```
ls -l /proc/$(pidof khostd)/exe
ls -l /proc/$(pidof khostd)/fd
cat /proc/$(pidof khostd)/stat
cat /proc/$(pidof khostd)/status
```

You can also use `lsof` to list all file descriptors used by this process:

```
lsof -a -p `pidof khostd`
```

or see what it is doing with:

```
strace -p `pidof khostd` -o /tmp/khostd.strace
```

Comment: So - WHAT is it?

Comment: Just posted some more info. I did a killall on it and it restarted itself. I'm suspecting this is a program that was inserted by my cloud hosting provider.

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: they deny ever installing this :(